# Manage NuGet Packages For Solution - where is it?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, nuget, nuget-package

I have just installed `VS2012` and have noticed that in the `Tools >> Library Package Manager` option that `Manage NuGet Packages For Solution` is missing.

`Package Manager Console` and `Package Manager Settings` are available but the option I mentioned is not there.

I attempted to download [Nuget](http://nuget.org/) and then restart `VS2012` but nothing has changed.

Also, when I installed `Vistual Studio` I included all the libraries available, so I am not sure how I have missed it?

Could anyone tell me how to get the `Manage NuGet Packages` option onto `VS2012`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I don't know if you can without opening a solution. Once you do go to the `Solution Explorer`, right click on solution and there is the option as `Manage NuGet Packages for Solution`. Opening the solution also makes appear extra options in the `Tools` -> `Library Package Manager`: `Manage NuGet Packages for Solution` and `Package Visualizer`.

**Edit**

As @atconway said in the comment, you can't do it while debugging.

Comment: It would help if I wasn't debugging when I was looking for this 'missing' option. :P Stop Debug, oh look it's there!

Comment: @atconway I would love to say that I have never done that, I really would... however... :)

Answer (score 2):

You must have it in debug mode, stop the if you are debugging and you will see 'Manage NuGet Package for solution' in the list.

Answer (score 1):

On the Tools menu, click the Extensions and updates.

Answer (score 1):

You might be in the debugging mode(application might be running).

Go to

> Debug-> Stop Debugging

Now you will be able to see "Manage NuGet Packages For Solution" under

> Tools> NuGet Package Manager> Manage NuGet Packages For Solution

Answer (score 1):

Tools > Extension Manager > Online Gallery;
You will see "Manage NuGet Packages For Solution" and press download.
After finishing download, Save your project first, and restart your Visual Studio, that's all.